# Get client IP address in a WCF Service hosted using HTTPS 443 bindings

Tags: c#, wcf, https, ip-address

In one of my application in need client IP address in a WCF Service hosted using HTTPS 443 bindings.

and i tried most of the post of stack overflow and other site regarding this issue but when i hosted my application in server it just fetch server IP address but i need requested client address any have any idea regarding this

Thanks In advance..

Comment: Don't forget that it will be possible only if you are not behind a reverse proxy, or a NAT bridge.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In .NET 3.5 you can do using the below pattern (using `System.ServiceModel`)

```
OperationContext context = OperationContext.Current; 
MessageProperties prop = context.IncomingMessageProperties; 
RemoteEndpointMessageProperty endpoint = prop[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
string ip = endpoint.Address;
```