# WCF Service retrying messages indefinitely

Tags: c#, wcf

Background:

I am seeing a weird situation in our production. We have a WCF service which has 2 endpoints exposed (HTTP and https). The HTTP endpoint uses Wshttpbinding with Security=Message and Authentication as Windows. The Https endpoint uses Wshttpbinding with Security=Transport and Authentication as Certificates. This service is consumed by 3 clients. Two of them use https endpoint to communicate and one client (windows service) uses HTTP endpoint.

Problem:

The WCF service is continuously processing messages which are not sent by any of the 3 clients mentioned. I tried to stop all the 3 clients and still the data flowing through the service. I am having a hard time to figure out from where these messages are being processed by the service. Is it possible that WCF service is caching any of the previously unprocessed messages? I have no idea on whats going on.

Below is the stuff I tried:

a) restarted the application pool several times, but that didn't resolve the issue.

b) Stopped and restarted all the 3 clients in different combinations just to make a filter out which one of these could be responsible for these messages. I had a situation where all 3 clients are turned off but still seeing the service processing messages.

c) I neither restarted the production server nor restarted the IIS, because it's on a production server and I am apprehensive to do so. But I can give it a shot if that resolves the issue and if there is any technical reason which can help in doing a restart.

I ran out of all the idea's and I would appreciate if I can try any inputs.

Comment: Sure, I will try that tomorrow. If you have any other inputs please let me know...

Comment: Thanks for your help Michal. I was able to figure out, it was the windows service client which was shooting messages to the WCF service. There were about 6000 pending requests which it queued up. Currently turned off the windows service and the WCF service seems to be behaving as expected...

Comment: Yep, done. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Wireshark http://wireshark.org/download.html to identify which host is sending packets to port 80 of the host running the web service... I'm pretty sure something stays running in one of the 3 clients that keeps sending requests....

You could also try this to identify which client sent the request directly in the code of your WCF service [Get client IP address in a WCF Service hosted using HTTPS 443 bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048532/)… and log it to the log file for example