# How to detect which machines are consuming or calling my WCF services?

Tags: wcf

I was curious if there are any way to find out which machine or client is calling my WCF hosted service. Is this tress-able from my host ?
Some sample/sudo code will be very much helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

See this answer: [Get client IP address in a WCF Service hosted using HTTPS 443 bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048532/get-client-ip-address-in-a-wcf-service-hosted-using-https-443-bindings) to get IP address of the client.

```
OperationContext context = OperationContext.Current; 
MessageProperties prop = context.IncomingMessageProperties; 
RemoteEndpointMessageProperty endpoint = prop[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
string ip = endpoint.Address;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you want but i hope this could help you:

```
var calledUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod + " " + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.OriginalString;
var iPAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
var userAgent = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent;
```

if you need anything else just let me know.